# Tcl/MySQL Query: comparing integer to seconds

Tags: mysql, tcl

I have a DB with a [clock seconds] value saved in a column "ablaufdatum".
I have a Tcl Script that gets the [clock seconds] from now and selects all older entries. But somehow the following Query is not working and I can't find out why. Can you help me?

```
set systemTime [clock seconds]
set queryanzahlalteuser [::mysql::query $db {SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_ticket WHERE aktiv='1' AND erstellt='1' AND ablaufdatum<'$systemTime'}]
```

ablaufdatum is also a ] but saved as an integer in a mysql DB.

This is not returing any values.
I tried

```
puts "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_ticket WHERE aktiv='1' AND erstellt='1' AND ablaufdatum<'$systemTime'"
```

and the shown query, if typed to the phpMyAdmin Console, works fine and returns values.

Is it possible that the Integer format is causing this?
Or do I have to format the current time differently?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar to mysql (I use sqlite more) but I checked the [manuals](http://www.xdobry.de/mysqltcl/mysqltcl.html#6) and it appears that the command `::mysql::query` does not undertake variable substitution when using braces, so try using the following instead:

```
set systemTime [clock seconds]
set queryanzahlalteuser [::mysql::query $db "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_ticket WHERE aktiv='1' AND erstellt='1' AND ablaufdatum<'$systemTime'"]
                                          # ^                                                                                              ^
```

Using double quotes instead should work.

Comment: And maybe remove the single quotes around the variable. I wouldn't recommend comparing an integer datatype against a string in a general sql perspective.

Comment: It seems that mysqltcl doesn't support parameterized SQL statements. I'd recommend tdbc::mysql (which follows the TDBC API) these days instead for exactly that reason.

Comment: thanks for the input, i looked into the tdbc::mysql but can't seem to find a lot of documentation...
I'm loading following packages (do i have to download them first or are these included in the Tcl Version 8.6? Is there a problem with the way i'm loading the package (Windows Server 2008 R2)?
package require tdbc
package require tdbc::mysql
The script just ends at that part...(i put "puts before" and "puts after" before and after this require and only the before shows...)

Comment: @Rory Sorry, I can't help you with the loading of those packages as I'm not familiar with them at all. I have the `tdbc` package on my Tcl8.6, but no `tdbc::mysql`.